# batch: How to give filename to variable

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm in need to filter a big list of files over and over with batch and therefore it would be a lot of work to edit the name of every file itselt inside the batch file. So I though about adding something like this

```
SET "CName=dir "U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\*.txt""
```

But apparently it won't work as intended. The goal would be to use this along with other variables but I can't manage to make it work. The name of the file always is something like .Complete.txt but it would be much harder to only set the  instead of just checking any file.

I though about something like this.

- Start loop While var CName isn't nul or empty
- Search for txt-file
- Edit txt-file
- Move txt-file
- Start loop again

I think this is actually something very simple but I haven't figured out how to pass the value from the result to the var. I've also tried this:

```
SET CName=*
dir "U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\*.txt" > %CName%
```

But this only gives me a very new file which is moved into that folder. :C

Edit:
Here is the current batch but I can't figure out how to make this work properly.

```
@ECHO off
    SET SPT="U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\%CNAME%.Complete.txt"
    SET SPT2="U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\%CNAME%.Filtrer.txt"
    SET SPT3="U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\%CNAME%.Temp.txt"
    SET SPT4="U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\Refiltered"
    SET SPT5="U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\%CNAME%.Programms.txt"

ECHO Cleaning Collected Entries ...
for %%a in ("U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\*.Complete.txt") do (
    SET CName=%%a
    echo Filename: %CName%

    ::Removing of all the already checked lines (Common programs only)
    type %SPT% | findstr /v /c:"Office Professional Plus 2016" | findstr /v /c:"Office Professional Plus 2013" | findstr /v /c:"Office Home and Business 2016" | findstr /v /c:"DisplayName    REG_SZ    Microsoft Office Professionnel Plus" | findstr /v /c:"Trend Micro" | findstr /v /c:"7-Zip"  | findstr /v /c:"QuickZip" | findstr /v /c:"Mozilla Firefox" | findstr /v /c:"Google Chrome" | findstr /v /c:"Opera" | findstr /v /c:".NET Framework 4.7" | findstr /v /c:".NET Framework 4.6" | findstr /v /c:".NET Framework 4.5" | findstr /v /c:"Adobe Acrobat Reader" | findstr /v /c:"Dynamics NAV 2015" | findstr /v /c:"MobaXterm" > %SPT2%
    ::Removing of all the already checked lines (Additional common programs)
    type %SPT2% | findstr /v /c:"PDFCreator" | findstr /v /c:"CDBurnerXP" | findstr /v /c:"Java 8" | findstr /v /c:"Java 7" | findstr /v /c:"Java 6" | findstr /v /c:"Java 5" | findstr /v /c:"paint.net" | findstr /v /c:"FileZilla Client" | findstr /v /c:"Notepad++" | findstr /v /c:"EaseUS Partition Master" > %SPT3%
    ::Removing all the unnecessary lines
    type %SPT3% | findstr /v "Word OneNote Access Excel Outlook PowerPoint InfoPath Publisher Skype Proofing Groove HPCLJProM452 Taalprogramma C++ UninstallLegacy linguistique Herramientas Korrekturhilfen DeskUpdate Plusÿ2016 Description" | findstr /v /c:"Logiciel pour p" | findstr /v /c:"USB 3.0 eXtensible Host" | findstr /v /c:"Intel(R) Network Connections" | findstr /v /c:"Mozilla Maintenance Service" | findstr /v /c:"System CLR Types" | findstr /v /c:"HP Color LaserJet Pro M452" | findstr /v /c:"64-bit Components" | findstr /v /c:"Visual Studio 2010 Tools" | findstr /v /c:"Adobe Refresh Manager" | findstr /v /c:"Realtek High Definition Audio" | findstr /v /c:"Processor Graphics" | findstr /v /c:"Report Viewer" | findstr /v /c:"HP Unified" | findstr /v /c:"Chipset Device Software" | findstr /v /c:"Management Engine Components" | findstr /v /c:"Office OSM" | findstr /v /c:"Open XML SDK" | findstr /v /c:"Recover Keys" | findstr /v /c:"Dynamics NAV Setup" | findstr /v /c:"DCF MUI" | findstr /v /c:"Office OSM" | findstr /v /c:"Office OSM" | findstr /v /c:"Office Shared" | findstr /v /c:"Components Installer" | findstr /v /c:"Java Auto Updater" > %SPT2%
    timeout 1 /nobreak > nul
    DEL %SPT3%
    timeout 1 /nobreak > nul
    move %SPT% %SPT4%
    move %SPT2% %SPT4%
)
ECHO Cleaning complete!
ECHO Please press any key to finish!
PAUSE > NUL
```

I am probably missing something. :/

Comment: `for %%F in ("U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\*.txt") do set "CName=%%~F"`; what should happen if multiple files match?

Comment: there are multiple files but it's impossible for a file to exist twice.

Comment: I meant different files but all of them matching the mask... ;-)

Comment: It does kinda work but `CName` doesn't really get the name of the files so it doesn't get them properly. Here is an excample of one of those filenames: `ADMIN04.YLQR008840.Complete` I only get an empty file because the variable doesn't get any value :C

Comment: If `ADMIN04.YLQR008840.Complete` is the complete file name, why do you specify pattern `*.txt` then? What file(s) do you actually want to search for? Please be as precise as possible! By the way, to get the pure name only without path, use `set "CName=%%~nxF"`...

Comment: It is not the only file I need to edit. I have to filter out many lines but editing the variable for every run would be so pointless. There are a few thousand files in there you know? So that's why I need that script in the first place. Else I wouldn't have to make the script.

Answer (score 0):

to get the output of a command to a variable, use a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s "U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\*.txt"') do set "file=%%a"
```

But `for` can handle filenames itself, making it slightly easier:

```
for %%a in ("U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\*.txt") do set "file=%%a"
```

Note both methods will return the *last* file, if more than one is found.

If you want to process each finding, include the code into the loop:

```
for %%a in ("U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\*.txt") do (
  echo found file %%a
  echo modifying %%a
  echo move "%%~a" "C:\temp\"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if the loop should process currently present files or
constantly waiting for new files with the extension `.Complete.txt` to arrive.
This batch does both with a `for` command and a called subroutine.

```
@Echo off
Set "BaseDir=U:\Morheng S\Partage\_Scans\Result ICT\Done (Filter rework)\"
PushD "%BaseDir%" || (Echo Can't locate %BaseDir% & PAuse & Exit /B 1)
Set Delay=30
:Loop
For %%F in (*.Complete.txt ) do Call :Sub %%F
Waiting for %Delay% seconds
Timeout %Delay%
goto :Loop

:Sub
Echo Processing %1
notepad %1
Echo move %1 x:\path\
```